# Entity framework in visual studio, manual changes not saved in model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

in Visual studio i have implemented the entity framework. However when ever the model.cs class in the model.t folder does not save my changes permanently. Every time i load the solution, the file gets auto generated. I understand this is supposed to happen, however i need to add additional constructors. Please tell me how to save my changed permanently.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can create partial class for your entity and make needed changes.